# changing the direction of contents of webforms in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Put simply: I want to move the "Email" text to the right side of the textbox because my language is Persian. Therefore after writing the Persian equivalent of email, still I have problems with moving the text to the right side of the textbox.

[image]

The solutions I have tried include: moving these lines:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
```

down and bringing these lines up before them:

```
 <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

It is the only solution that works so far. But are there better and more convenient solutions?
I already have tried using `dir="rtl"` in both `html` tag and also inside `p` and `div` tags but it does not work.
Thanks

```
@model Website_File_Store.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  IMAGES of code are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding a css style in css style file:

```
.control-label {
    float: right;
}
```